# What home products are reactive with glass?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, glass

Glass seems to be one of the most stable solid substances - which chemicals, particularly home products that react with glass?

Comment: Drain cleaner (concentrated solutions of NaOH) but very slowly.

Comment: Hydrofluoric acid (HF) is an effective substance to dissolve Glass.

Its also very effective in killing you in a very slow and very painful way (by basically dissolving your bones).

Comment: Actually, HF kills you by depositing CaF2 in your microcapillaries. Blood flow in extremities diminishes to zero over a few hours, leading to cell death and gangrene. It is possible to reverse the process if it has not progressed too far, but it is a hospital-type procedure. Definitely painful.

Comment: Well, HF can hardly be considered as a home product, frequently used/found in households.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some rust and stain removers (like Whink) contain hydrofluoric acid* at low concentrations (1-2.3%) Here is the MSDS for Whink: https://www.whink.com/cmssites/ws0811www.whink.com/uploads/Documents/Rust%20Stain%20Remover%20SDS.pdf

Now, at those concentrations it would probably take a while to dissolve silica, but it would be arguably quicker than a $\ce{NaOH}$ cleaning product.

*I do not recommend playing around with $\ce{HF}$ and its products unless you are experienced with them.